# Confusion about enqueue-ing datas into circular-queue recursively

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, queue, circular-queue

In fact, this is not a main problem, I encountered this issue while doing practice about BST traversal with circular-queue.

I tried to define inorder traversal recursively and so enqueue-ing data also defined recursively.

Here is some example which I tried as below :

```
typedef int element;
typedef struct { 
    element  data[MAX_QUEUE_SIZE];
    int  front, rear;
} QueueType;

void init_queue(QueueType* q)
{
    q->front = q->rear = 0;
}

int is_full(QueueType* q)
{
    return ((q->rear + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE == q->front);
}

void enqueue(QueueType* q, element item)
{
    if (is_full(q))
        error("Queue is full");
    q->rear = (q->rear + 1) % MAX_QUEUE_SIZE;
    q->data[q->rear] = item;
}

void q_factorial_enqueue(QueueType* q, int data)
{
    enqueue(q, data);
    if (data != 0)
    {
        q_factorial_enqueue(q, data - 1);
    }
}

void queue_print(QueueType* q)
{
    printf("QUEUE(front=%d rear=%d) = ", q->front, q->rear);
    if (!is_empty(q)) {
        int i = q->front;
        do {
            i = (i + 1) % (MAX_QUEUE_SIZE);
            printf("%d | ", q->data[i]);
        } while (i == q->rear);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And here is main function as below :

```
int main(void)
{
    QueueType queue;
    int element;

    init_queue(&queue); //Initialization

    q_factorial_enqueue(&queue, 5);
    queue_print(&queue);
}
```

I want to enqueue datas '5 4 3 2 1' to circular-queue but If I print elements of circular-queue, there is no correct input also there is no output because there is no input.

What did I miss to define enqueue recursively?

Comment: Can you paste the input and output? Also show us how you are printing the queue.

Comment: "there is no correct input" What does that mean? You are not asking for any input. How can it be not correct?

Comment: There is nothing in queue although I executed "enqueue(q, data)". @Gerhardh

Comment: How do you check the content? What does `queue_print` do?

Comment: Let me upload it soon, @Karthick

Comment: If I run your code (without the missing functions) I get 6 values added to the circular buffer which is what I would expect. With `#define MAX_QUEUE_SIZE 10` I get this buffer: `{0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }` and `front==0` , `rear == 6`

Comment: I edited context `queue_print` @Gerhardh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253819/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-bfur4list).